# having issue running ruby on rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem running RoR project. I am getting this error while running it "Mysql2::Error
Unknown database 'simple_cms_development'"
I have no idea what to do with this issue and how to resolve it. Anyone who can helo me. Thanks in advance

Here is bt database.yml file

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "123456"
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the database created in MySQL?  If it's not, you can try running `rake db:create` to try and have rails create it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Unkown database means the database `simple_cms_development` doesn't exist yet. If the user root already exists with the password 123456 you can just run `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate`.

These are commands run from the commandline inside the directory of your rails project